# Issue in learning Apache Pig programming

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to Hadoop learning hadoop myself,i am not a java guy, so i am giving  more interest to pig,hive and learned so many things,while learning UDF i have a doubt ,UDF is using java ,what kind of java knowledge is required to work on this,i studied some where it is using **java script api** for coding ,can anyone please tell me what kind of java knowledge is required for writing the UDF.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: basic understanding of java is sufficient to write Pig UDF. Instead of Java you can use Python, JavaScript or Ruby to do the same. For more details you can [check this](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/udf.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basic knowledge of java is needed to UDF in pig.

Refer https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/udf.html

if you were a .net guy try C# streaming concept to create udfs in windows platform.